# URL mod rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

changing these urls with .htaccess file

**website.com/b.php?g=666** to **website.com/666**

and

**website.com/g/2/1.gif** to **website.com/2/1**

How is this done

also simple examples to learn how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: There are many web pages on the web that give examples.  Google for "url rewriting htaccess".  The very first hit is in the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put this inside your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /b.php?g=$1 [L]
```

to make your first pattern work.  If you want more than just `b.php` to work (you want it to work with *any* PHP file) you can modify the rule according to your needs.  (The question did not specify how general the rule should be.)

Whether it works or not will depend on whether such settings are enabled in the main httpd.conf file.  In other words, Apache might be set up to *not* allow you to use the rewrite engine in your `.htaccess` file.  YMMV.

To understand how these work, browse through [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/), especially examples on [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html).

You can also try your luck with something like a [rewrite rule generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/), but it's good to read the docs as well so you have some idea of what the generated rule does.

The second one might work with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)([^/]*)$ /g/$1/$2.gif [L]
```

(Of course you don't need to put "RewriteEngine On" twice, if you're using the first one as well.)

Comment: ok cheers for the first bit but I don't understand how to do the second one aswell??

Comment: I'm working on that, but it's tough because I can't experiment on your web server to verify that my rule works.... I'm limited to a purely rationalistic approach.

Comment: Ah ok thanks very much. Are you able to do the second one and forget about the first one?

Answer (score 0):

For internally rewriting a request for `http://website.com/666` to `/b.php?g=666`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /b.php?g=$1 [L]
```

For internally rewrite a request for `http://website.com/2/1` to `/g/2/1.gif`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/g/%1/%2.gif -f
RewriteRule ^ /g/%1/%2.gif [L]
```